# Display Images from Mysql database in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I save image path and image name in myqsl database. Now I want to display images from database on asp.net data-list. I have query result like this
[image]

I want to display picture with pageName. I do some thing like this on datalst.

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtlistImages" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                        BorderColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="2px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("pageName") %>' Font-Bold="true"
                            Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#336699" Width="100%"/>
                            </br>
                 <asp:Image ID="imgnewspaper" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("pageNumber") %>' />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Top" />    
    </asp:DataList>
```

Code Behind:

```
  public DataTable getData(string query)
        {
            MySqlConnection conn1 = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString);
            conn1.Open();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn1);
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        protected void btnshow_onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string query = "select cap_newspaper_page.pageServer,cap_newspaper_page.pagePath, pageNumber,pageName,newspaper.newspaperName,newspaper_station.newspaperStationName"+
                            " FROM cap_newspaper_page Inner Join cap_newspaper ON cap_newspaper_page.capnewspaperID = cap_newspaper.capnewspaperID inner join newspaper on newspaper.newspaperID=cap_newspaper.newspaperID"+
                            " inner join newspaper_station on newspaper_station.newspaperStationID=cap_newspaper.newspaperStationID where cap_newspaper.newspaperID="+ddlNewspaper.SelectedValue+" and cap_newspaper.newspaperStationID="+ddlNewspaperStation.SelectedValue+" and cap_newspaper_page.publishDate='"+tbDate.Text+" 00:00:00'";
            dtlistImages.DataSource = getData(query);           
            dtlistImages.DataBind();
        }
```

but display is like this
[image]

How I can Display images also dynamically. based on query.

Comment: where you put actual images in drive?

Comment: I want to get images direct from database based on query result. therefor not any image folder is placed. Is there necessary to place image folder???

Comment: Not necessary to place image folder. But as I can see there only name of image in database. if you need to display image from database then you need to stored image content in DB.

Comment: I does not save image in binary format. Image table have serverpath like 172.168.456.236 page path like printImages/0150/21022013/ and images name like 0150_21022013_001.jpg. now this the help of these values images should be displayed on datalist control based on query from database. What are the possible ways to do this???

Answer (score 1):

what does the source code for the compiled html look like?  clearly the image paths must be invalid.  if you check what the asp has written does this not give a strong clue as to what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You only have pageNumber and not pagePath in your Eval

Comment: This should probably be a comment, since it doesn't directly answer the main question asked.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question then. Apparently you get your display of images messed up. They are not showing. If you add the path then this will go away...

Comment: In your defense, it isn't the clearest question, true. Your answer might help, it might not; depending on details op hasn't given us, I guess.

Comment: I write pagePath on Eval but not displayed any images

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Image ID="imgnewspaper" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#  Eval("pagePath") %>' />
```

or
you are missing the images in your project folder `printImages` locally, if your are running it locally, and if you are running it on live server then also check that folder for images.

**Suggestion** I have achieved the same thing in the following way:

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ImagesList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" GroupItemCount="4"  OnPagePropertiesChanging="ImagesList_PagePropertiesChanging">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No Images found.
         </EmptyDataTemplate>
          <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:ImageButton ID="MyPicture" runat="server" OnClick="MyPicture_Click" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'  AlternateText='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' Autopostback="true"Width="155" Height="80" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: I want to display images from live server

Comment: on your suggested listview, what OnClick="MyPicture_Click" do?

Comment: its a event, if someone clicks on the displayed image

Comment: DataKeyNames="ID" OnPagePropertiesChanging="ImagesList_PagePropertiesChanging" what will place in datakeyname and what will OnPagePropertiesChanging="ImagesList_PagePropertiesChanging" do?

Comment: thats for changing page index